# Numpy array: how to reduce a single dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

If I have an array of shape (500, 363, 3) which looks like the one below, how can I reduce it to shape (500, 363, 1) where each value will be a single bool equivalent to the result of all(). So [False, False, False] would become False?

```
Array([[[False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    ...,
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]],

   [[False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    ...,
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]],

   [[False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    ...,
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]],

   ...,

   [[False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    ...,
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]],

   [[False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    ...,
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]],

   [[False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    ...,
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]]])
```

Comment: `arr.all(axis=2)` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may do

```py
import numpy as np
reduced = np.all(arr, axis = 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html) has an axis argument, in this case you want to take `all` along the last axis, so you need:

```
a.all(-1)
```

---

```
a = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(500, 363, 3))
print(a.all(-1).shape)
# (500, 363)
```